# print statement is not working in python proboscis

Tags: python, unit-testing, functional-testing, nose

We started writing our functional and unit test cases in python using nose framework. We started  learning python while writing these tests. Since there are lot of dependencies between our test classes/functions, we decided to use [proboscis framework](http://packages.python.org/proboscis/) on top of nose to control order of execution.

We have quite a few 'print' statements in our tests and proboscis seems to be ignoring these! Tests are running in expected order and testing them all but not printing our print statement data to console. Any idea what we are missing here?

BTW, we stopped deriving our classes from 'unittest.TestCase' once we moved to proboscis and decorated all classes and their member functions with @test.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: @Tichodroma: I think it's clear they already tried something; using `print` in tests under the proboscis framework...

Comment: `nose` captures stdout and only displays it for failed tests. What's your motivation for using `print`? Have you considered the `logging` module, if you're using `print` to debug?

Comment: Its look like, for us, Nose stdout all print statements in success/fail tests! Some of our tests are reading multiple sets of inputs from a file, so we are printing result for each input set and some other basic data like time, size of input, etc. We haven't looked into logging module but definitely check it out. Thanks for mensioning about it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: According to the *Proboscis* [documentation](http://packages.python.org/proboscis/) *"unused arguments get passed along to Nose or the unittest module"*, so the following should apply to *Proboscis* by replacing `nosetests` with `python run_tests.py`.

As @Wooble has mentioned in his comment, by default `nose` captures `stdout` and only displays it for failed tests. You can override this behaviour with the `nosetests` `-s` or `--nocapture` switch:

```
$ nosetests --nocapture
```

Like @Wooble also mentions in his comment, I recommend using the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module instead of `print`. Then you only need to pass `nosetests` the `-l DEBUG` or `--debug=DEBUG` switch, where `DEBUG` is replaced by a comma separated list of the names of the loggers you want to display, to enable displaying of the logging output from your modules:

```
$ nosetests --debug=your-logger-name
```

Comment: You both are correct, Nose only displays failed tests. We were using -s -v options by default with nose command to report all. Now we are leaning towards using logging module. Thanks to both of you for helping us.